# Magento 2.3.2 Customer Grid not showing data

Tags: magento2, customer

I am using Magento 2.3.2 there lot of customers registered and available in the database but not showing in the Customer Grid, cron job, and indexer are also working all other grids are working except Customers.
When I inspect element it shows some warning of duplicate elements as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:status` showed customer_grid index was suspended.
So I reset and run the indexer again using the below command and it started working.

`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid`

`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex`